# Shopify Authentication Validation with Firebase?

Tags: javascript, node.js, firebase, shopify, next.js

I've been following [this](https://shopify.dev/tutorials/build-a-shopify-app-with-node-and-react) tutorial on how to build a public Shopify app using Node, Nextjs and React.

Everything is going well, however I am now at a point where I need to store some of my app data in a database. For this, I've chosen Firestore.

What I am doing is when the user authenticates the app with their store, I use the Admin-SDK within my Next JS server to write their shop and accessToken to a document:

> Note: I'm using the accessMode "offline" as I need a permanent access token so that my app can make Shopify API requests in the background.  I also know that I should really encrypt the accessToken before storing it, however just trying to get the logic working first

```
server.use(
    createShopifyAuth({
        apiKey: SHOPIFY_API_KEY,
        secret: SHOPIFY_API_SECRET_KEY,
        scopes: ['read_products', 'write_products'],
        accessMode: "offline",
        async afterAuth(ctx) {
            const {shop, accessToken} = ctx.session;

            ctx.cookies.set('shopOrigin', shop, {
                httpOnly: false,
                secure: true,
                sameSite: 'none'
            });

            await getSubscriptionUrl(ctx, accessToken, shop);
            await db.collection('shops').doc(shop).set({
                name: shop,
                accessToken
            }, {merge: true});
        },
    }),
);
```

I am also using the Koa middleware which validates any requests to my app to ensure they are from a Shopify app

```
server.use(verifyRequest());
```

What I now want to do is to add a way for my app to pull data from Firebase.  I've created an api endpoint within `/pages/api/firebase.js` that uses the `shopOrigin` cookie to get the store name, and then pull the data for that store.

```
export default async(req, res) => {
        const shop = req.cookies.shopOrigin;
        const doc = await db.collection('shops').doc(shop).get()
        res.status(200).json({success: true, data: doc.data()});
    }
```

The problem I'm facing though, is that a user can simply just change that cookies value and pull data for another store.  The `verifyRequest` function doesn't seem to check if the shopOrigin name calling it is from the store that calls it.

Does anyone know how I can validate these requests, so that the store calling my API can only access that stores data (via the admin-sdk on the Next server)?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Thinking about this, I can use a custom authentication method.

Within the Next server.js file, the below creates a custom token using the shop name, and then sets that token in a cookie. For the example, it then creates a document in the shops collection with the document ID as the store name.

```
async afterAuth(ctx) {
    const {shop, accessToken} = ctx.session;

    await getSubscriptionUrl(ctx, accessToken, shop);

    const customToken = await admin.auth().createCustomToken(shop)

    ctx.cookies.set('shopOrigin', shop, {
        httpOnly: false,
        secure: true,
        sameSite: 'none'
    });

    ctx.cookies.set('token', customToken, {
        httpOnly: false,
        secure: true,
        sameSite: 'none'
    });

    await db.collection('shops').doc(shop).set({
        domain: shop,
        token: cryptr.encrypt(accessToken),
    }, {merge: true});
},
```

Within the React app, initialise your Firebase App instance and then within the index.js listen to see if the authState changed or log the user in using the token.

```
useEffect(() => {
    firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged(user => {
        if(user) {
            setSignedIn(true)
        } else {
            firebase.auth().signInWithCustomToken(Cookies.get('token'));
        }
    })
},[])
```

Then in the Firebase rules, set your permissions as required

```
match /shops/{shop}/{documents=**} {
    allow read, write: if request.auth != null && request.auth.uid == shop
}
```

Comment: Where did you call `admin.initializeApp()`?

Comment: @K20GH awesome, however I run into the problem that admin has not been initialised - where did you call / import that?