# Firebase and Shopify - securing database question

Tags: reactjs, database, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, authorization

Currently I am working on a Shopify app in React that interacts with a Firestore database. For some time now I have been getting the "Insecure Rules" email and have been trying to fix it (as you will see from my post history). So far I have tried rewriting the rules but realised I need some sort of unique identifier for each store to enable secure database access. So far I have followed an answer found here but now my project won't run due to an error I believe is related to this.

I was lucky enough to find [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62472778/shopify-authentication-validation-with-firebase/62491293#comment117576791_62491293) that gave me a good idea of what to do, however the poster did not write how the 'customToken' value was given by calling the `admin.auth().createCustomToken(shop)`function. To my knowledge, this is the `react-admin-firebase` [package](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-admin-firebase), which I have now installed. I have tried to set it up by providing a service account using the following code.

```
admin.initializeApp({ 
  serviceAccountId: 'example@serviceaccount.com',
});`
```

I have imported it as `const admin = require('react-admin');` in the `server.js` file as specified in the post, however I have two questions:

1. This message is printed - `{"severity":"WARNING","message":"Warning, FIREBASE_CONFIG and GCLOUD_PROJECT environment variables are missing. Initializing firebase-admin will fail"} Browserslist: caniuse-lite is outdated. Please run: npx browserslist@latest --update-db` - **a)** does this mean I need to do `require('firebase-admin')` instead of `react-admin`, or **b)** do I need to insert the `FIREBASE_CONFIG` and `GCLOUD_PROJECT` variables somewhere? I saw [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65536660/how-to-set-firebase-config-and-gcloud-project-in-firebase-project) that this error is being produced because I am not running a firebase server - **c)** does this mean I can't use the library if I can't set it? Also, I ran the `npx` browser command and still got the same error.

2. Am I doing something completely wrong?

Any feedback would be greatly appreciated, I have been stuck on this for a while and completely out of ideas!